# Trying to figure out best way to manipulate file with multiple records, some with duplicates and dates

Tags: sorting, awk, sed

I have a file which contains multiple rows of data and some are duplicates with date field at end of record. I want to be able to scan the file and keep the most current record for duplicates but some records may contain users with multiple unique rows and same date and I want to leave these intact. Here's an example of what the data looks like:

```
00xbdf0c9fd6;joe@easy.us.com;20141231 <- remove this one
00vbdf0c9fd6;joe@easy.us.com;20150403 <- keep this one (newer date)
00zbef2c9fdx;joe@easy.us.com;20141231 <-keep
00dbkf0ca292;jerry@easy.us.com;20141231 <-keep
0dbds0ca2f6;john@easy.us.com;20141231 <- remove
0dbds0ca2f6;john@easy.us.com;20150403 <- keep (newer date)
00dndf0ca080;betty@easy.us.com;20141231 <-keep
00dbkf0ca292;betty@easy.us.com;20141231 <-keep
00dxdf2ca08x;betty@easy.us.com;20141231 <-keep
00dtkf1ca294;betty@easy.us.com;20141231 <-keep
```

Thanks

Comment: Is it sure that the lines are in order, meaning a newer one will follow an older one?

Comment: Is the first field on the first two lines supposed to be the same ? Otherwise i don't understand the logic for removing.

Comment: Ops, yes the first fields on first two lines are supposed to be the same, sorry..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is sure that the lines are in order, meaning that newer lines will follow older lines, you can use the following `awk` script:

```
awk -F\; '{a[$1,$2]=$0}END{for(i in a){print a[i]}}' file
```

Comment: Whats with the split you can just use `print a[i]`

Comment: No idea, 3rd line i get `0dbds0ca2f6;john@easy.us.com;20150403`. Maybe an empty line at the end of your file ?

Comment: Since the file is already sorted the shorter version of awk from hek2mg seems to work fine. Thank You all very much for your help, I appreciate it! 

DR

Comment: awk -F\; '{a[$1,$2]=$0}END{for(i in a){print a[i]}}' file

This works fine from cmd line but when I add it to existing perl script and enclose in ` ` I get these errors and it doesn't work?

awk: {a[";"]=a[";"]>?a[";"]:}END{for(i in a)print i FS a[i]}
awk:                ^ syntax error
awk: {a[";"]=a[";"]>?a[";"]:}END{for(i in a)print i FS a[i]}
awk:                       ^ syntax error

Comment: You can't add awk to an existing perl script. awk is a programming language. However, you can call it through `system()` http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html

Comment: You are welcome. Btw, if you already working with perl, why don't you prefer the perl solution?

Comment: The one liner looked smaller and I thought I could easily call it directly from perl or rexx but your correct, would be easier to just incorporate that code into an existing perl script. Thx

Comment: I would use a pure perl solution, or a pure awk solution

Answer (score 0):

Should probably do it

```
 awk -F";" '{a[$1";"$2]=a[$1";"$2]>$3?a[$1";"$2]:$3}END{for(i in a)print i FS a[i]}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a typo on the first or the second line: the first column should be identical for them.

Here's a Perl solution:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %seen;
while (<>) {
    my ($id, $user, $date) = split /;/;
    $seen{$id}{$user} = [$date, $.] if $date gt ($seen{$id}{$user}[0] // q());
}

my @l = sort { $a->[3] <=> $b->[3] } # Sort by line number.
        map { my $id = $_; map [ $id, $_, @{ $seen{$id}{$_} } ],
                               keys %{ $seen{$_} }
            }
        keys %seen;
print join ';', @{$_}[0, 1, 2] for @l;
```